# Undelete in SVN working copy

Tags: svn

Having just called:

```
svn rm someDirectory
```

but *not having committed*, how do I undelete the directory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
svn revert --recursive <folder_name>
```

Will back out any changes recursively from folder_name downwards

Comment: Ah, recursive! That's what I was missing. Thanks!